# Error when re-tweeting multiple times

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, foreach

I am trying to have a single tweet be re-tweeted by a list of people.

The list of people is in my database. Here's my query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $users[] = $row;
}
```

I am trying to iterate though this list with a foreach loop. The problem is that only the first person on the list re-tweets. For the others it gives an error saying:

```
stdClass Object ( [message] => Invalid or expired token [code] => 89 )
```

As for my foreach loop:

```
foreach($users as $value){

    $oauth_token = $value['oauth_token'];
    $oauth_secret = $value['oauth_secret'];

    $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth('****', '****', $oauth_token, $oauth_secret);

    $result = $twitteroauth->post('statuses/retweet/'.$tweet_id);

}
```

This is what i get for the first loop through:

```
stdClass Object ( [in_reply_to_status_id] => [user] => stdClass Object ( [name] => hamid [profile_background_color] => C0DEED [lang] => en [screen_name] => rumble909 [id] => 261675207 [profile_background_image_url] => http://a0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png [verified] => [default_profile] => 1 [notifications] => [profile_link_color] => 0084B4 [profile_image_url_https] => https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_3_normal.png [statuses_count] => 14 [contributors_enabled] => [id_str] => 261675207 [profile_use_background_image] => 1 [following] => [utc_offset] => [profile_text_color] => 333333 [created_at] => Sun Mar 06 13:04:44 +0000 2011 [listed_count] => 0 [profile_image_url] => http://a0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_3_normal.png [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/images/themes/theme1/bg.png [time_zone] => [follow_request_sent] => [protected] => [profile_sidebar_border_color] => C0DEED [description] => [friends_count] => 5 [followers_count] => 2 [profile_background_tile] => [default_profile_image] => 1 [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => DDEEF6 [url] => [entities] => stdClass Object ( [description] => stdClass Object ( [urls] => Array ( ) ) ) [favourites_count] => 0 [is_translator] => [geo_enabled] => [location] => ) [in_reply_to_screen_name] => [id_str] => 349183887999635456 [retweeted_status] => stdClass Object ( [in_reply_to_status_id] => [user] => stdClass Object ( [name] => TwtrAlert [profile_background_color] => C0DEED [lang] => nl [screen_name] => TwtrAlert [id] => 1468194638 [profile_background_image_url] => http://a0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png [verified] => [default_profile] => 1 [notifications] => [profile_link_color] => 0084B4 [profile_image_url_https] => https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/profile_images/3758330661/9c75fdc8679415b11d570a92534339a5_normal.png [statuses_count] => 14 [contributors_enabled] => [id_str] => 1468194638 [profile_use_background_image] => 1 [following] => [utc_offset] => [profile_text_color] => 333333 [created_at] => Wed May 29 20:29:45 +0000 2013 [listed_count] => 0 [profile_image_url] => http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/3758330661/9c75fdc8679415b11d570a92534339a5_normal.png [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/images/themes/theme1/bg.png [time_zone] => [follow_request_sent] => [protected] => [profile_sidebar_border_color] => C0DEED [description] => Doneer 10 Tweets per jaar voor de belangrijkste meldingen van Nederland. Meld je nu aan door in te loggen op: #Amberalert [friends_count] => 0 [followers_count] => 0 [profile_background_tile] => [default_profile_image] => [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => DDEEF6 [url] => [entities] => stdClass Object ( [description] => stdClass Object ( [urls] => Array ( ) ) ) [favourites_count] => 0 [is_translator] => [geo_enabled] => [location] => ) [in_reply_to_screen_name] => [id_str] => 349183884652580864 [contributors] => [geo] => [created_at] => Mon Jun 24 15:15:00 +0000 2013 [favorited] => [truncated] => [source] => Nessesis [entities] => stdClass Object ( [user_mentions] => Array ( ) [urls] => Array ( ) [hashtags] => Array ( ) ) [place] => [id] => 3.4918388465258E+17 [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => [coordinates] => [in_reply_to_user_id] => [retweet_count] => 1 [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => [text] => .... [retweeted] => 1 ) [contributors] => [geo] => [created_at] => Mon Jun 24 15:15:01 +0000 2013 [favorited] => [truncated] => [source] => Nessesis [entities] => stdClass Object ( [user_mentions] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id_str] => 1468194638 [id] => 1468194638 [screen_name] => TwtrAlert [indices] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 13 ) [name] => TwtrAlert ) ) [hashtags] => Array ( ) [urls] => Array ( ) ) [place] => [id] => 3.4918388799964E+17 [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => [coordinates] => [in_reply_to_user_id] => [retweet_count] => 1 [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => [text] => RT @TwtrAlert: .... [retweeted] => 1 )
```

and those after get the error above:

```
stdClass Object ( [message] => Invalid or expired token [code] => 89 )
```

Someone please tell me whats wrong with my code because i can't tell.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

It seems that the TwitterOauth differs between the first and the second.

First loop-through:

```
TwitterOAuth Object ( [http_code] => 200 [url] => https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/352047945522229248.json [host] => https://api.twitter.com/1.1/ [timeout] => 30 [connecttimeout] => 30 [ssl_verifypeer] => [format] => json [decode_json] => 1 [http_info] => Array ( [url] => https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/352047945522229248.json [content_type] => application/json; charset=utf-8 [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 1339 [request_size] => 481 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.979719 [namelookup_time] => 3.4E-5 [connect_time] => 0.099769 [pretransfer_time] => 0.307282 [size_upload] => 273 [size_download] => 3919 [speed_download] => 4000 [speed_upload] => 278 [download_content_length] => 3919 [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 0.979687 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) ) [useragent] => TwitterOAuth v0.2.0-beta2 [sha1_method] => OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1 Object ( ) [consumer] => OAuthConsumer Object ( [key] => ***** [secret] => ***** [callback_url] => ) [token] => OAuthConsumer Object ( [key] => 261675207-coNLDFjVXfbN9LLUnlcBAEt2fQAgf8d98iKGqHkT [secret] => YRiSvCkPDXf8S59Pv2AUkoGxUq5VGGxJGQz2PGlVSo [callback_url] => ) [http_header] => Array ( [cache_control] => no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0 [content_length] => 3919 [content_type] => application/json; charset=utf-8 [date] => Tue, 02 Jul 2013 12:55:46 GMT [etag] => "2419a11ea1bf2086f5084b7b09da6c52" [expires] => Tue, 31 Mar 1981 05:00:00 GMT [last_modified] => Tue, 02 Jul 2013 12:55:46 GMT [pragma] => no-cache [server] => tfe [set_cookie] => guest_id=v1%3A137276974644131212; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 02-Jul-2015 12:55:47 UTC [status] => 200 OK [strict_transport_security] => max-age=631138519 [vary] => Accept-Encoding [x_access_level] => read-write [x_frame_options] => SAMEORIGIN [x_mid] => 1df98af5f5d625dc987acc730e6e3f3985f451e0 [x_runtime] => 0.38122 [x_transaction] => 04aac3ca1caa40b3 [x_transaction_mask] => a6183ffa5f8ca943ff1b53b5644ef114d41f4c7d ) )
```

Second loop-through:

```
TwitterOAuth Object ( [http_code] => 401 [url] => https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/352047945522229248.json [host] => https://api.twitter.com/1.1/ [timeout] => 30 [connecttimeout] => 30 [ssl_verifypeer] => [format] => json [decode_json] => 1 [http_info] => Array ( [url] => https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweet/352047945522229248.json [content_type] => application/json; charset=utf-8 [http_code] => 401 [header_size] => 306 [request_size] => 481 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.417521 [namelookup_time] => 3.6E-5 [connect_time] => 0.099975 [pretransfer_time] => 0.309829 [size_upload] => 273 [size_download] => 61 [speed_download] => 146 [speed_upload] => 653 [download_content_length] => 61 [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 0.417509 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) ) [useragent] => TwitterOAuth v0.2.0-beta2 [sha1_method] => OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1 Object ( ) [consumer] => OAuthConsumer Object ( [key] => ****** [secret] => ***** [callback_url] => ) [token] => OAuthConsumer Object ( [key] => 1218650107-KPo4mx9rRwHcfXIqYXF3NyUy7ZUfLzufyplPabQ [secret] => L0zsMdR4Q1zQsB5VyGLhNf990F9ENgn2ddsjXADLI [callback_url] => ) [http_header] => Array ( [content_length] => 61 [content_type] => application/json; charset=utf-8 [date] => Tue, 02 Jul 2013 12:55:47 UTC [server] => tfe [set_cookie] => guest_id=v1%3A137276974742435806; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 02-Jul-2015 12:55:47 UTC [strict_transport_security] => max-age=631138519 ) )
```

Comment: Can you explain what the `****`s are in your code? Is this a username and password, or is it a post ID to retweet?

Comment: @ChristianStewart These are my Consumer Key and Consumer Secret for my twitter app.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I don't know, but I think it would be good to put an echo statement in your loop to check if it's actually looping

Comment: @ChristianStewart I have updated my question. It is indeed looping

Comment: Perhaps Twitter is rejecting it because there are so many coming in at once? You should add a bit of delay between each iteration

Comment: @ChristianStewart Really sorry for the late response, i have been really busy last week. Anyways, i used sleep() to delay each iteration for 10 seconds and nothing has changed. Found out something though. Updated my question.

Comment: Yeah, error 401 is indicating Unauthorized, the type of response you would get if either A. your oauth keys are outdated or B. they're wrong or C. you're doing something too quickly.